"Preferred but not necessary - we will train" (= "We will undergo training" or "We will train (you)"?) - see the context
Here's an example job ad from a ZNO prep website:

We are looking for someone to join our team as a
Newspaper Admin and Production Assistant on a part-time basis, 1-2 days per week. Monday and Thursday, 9 AM-1 PM. We are looking for someone who has:

experience with Quickbooks and Indesign (preferred but not necessary - we will train)
[…]


I am wondering what they meant by "preferred but not necessary - we will train" and how idiomatic it sounds in the attached image:

"We will undergo training"
"We will train (you)"


Obviously it means We will train you (the successful applicant) if you don't know Quickbooks. They're hardly likely to place a recruitment ad saying they intend to get themselves trained in Quickbooks! Note that We will undergo training can only mean We will be trained [by others], but without context, We will undertake training could carry either sense (we train others, or others train us).

It doesn't sound objectionable, though adding "you" wouldn't either.

it sounds like spam (at least borderline) to me

@Vickel That one phrase, or the entire job ad?

@Barmar, the whole thing is spammy. I'd edit out the link and the image and change the question to something like: I found an add with the following sentence ....

@Vickel The link just goes to the English quiz that uses the ad as the example. It's helpful to see the context when answering.

It's an item in a Ukrainian English course test. The Rocky Mountain Goat does exist, and their phones do have a Canadian 250 area code.

I was not 100% sure about this, so didn't red flag but commented here, just don't understand why they didn't remove the orange box with the contact numbers/email part

They have been rather terse with the way they have described the person they are looking for. That sentence means

We would prefer applicants who already know how to use Quickbooks and
Indesign, but we will train a successful candidate who does not.

They are also looking for a car owner.

How idiomatic is the original text?

@Wittyhaire It's idiomatic. Text in ads is often terse like this.

@Barmar You mean, a verb that cannot normally be used in a particular meaning intransitively nevertheless can be used so in a terse ad?

@Wittyhaire Yes. The object of the verb is often left implicit. You can also leave out the subject: "experience preferred, but will train".

@Barmar Is often left implicit? Apart from ads, where else can this usage be found?

Signs and headlines are other areas where we use terse language. E.g. "No smoking" is not a grammatical sentence.
